# Import DevOps CSV issues to existing user story without overwriting title and description?

Tags: csv, azure-devops, import

I'm working with Azure Devops and I want to import a CSV with about 20 issues and link them to an existing user story. After reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops), I've created the CSV file below and this seems to work, it creates the new issues ready for import.

```
ID,Work Item Type,Title 1,Title 2,Description 2,Assigned To,State,Priority,Tags
"112096","User Story","GPRI Beat 202200257 (GPRI forms)",,,,"New",,
,"Issue",,"Test issue 123 (a)","desc 1",,"New","1",
,"Issue",,"Test issue 456 (b)","desc 2",,"New","1",
```

However, this somehow requires that I also provide the title and description of the existing user story. In other words it will overwrite the existing title and description with whatever is provided in the CSV import file.

I kind of assumed that the `2` in `Description 2` meant that it only applied to child issues, i.e. the new issues and not the parent user story. When this description is empty then the existing description of the user story is erased and the import screen (correctly) shows an error and stops any import. See screenshots below.

The existing user story:
[image: existing user story with a title and description]

The csv import file:
[image: import CSV file with new issues]

Preview changes before saving the import:
[image]

So my question is; **is there a way to import new issues to an existing user story without changing the user story?** So ideally just provide the user story ID (in this example it's 112096) in the CSV file.

I've tried making the `Title 1` value empty in the import file, but then I get this error `Empty field value at line 2, column(s) 3, 4.`. I've also tried removing the column `Title 1` entirely, so just keep `Title 2`, but then it also gives the same "Empty field" error.

EDIT: I've also tried removing the "User Story" record and instead add `Parent` column, but that gives the error `Value of a readonly field Parent was modified. Please revert the Parent values or remove the column from the input file and and try to import again.`

Answer (score 0):

When using CSV files to export / import work items, the the **Work Item Type** and the **Title** fields are required. However, the other fields are optional.

I have attempted, and can add new child items to an existing parent item without changing the parent.

Below are the steps I did:

1. On Azure DevOps, go to "**Boards**" > "**Queries**" and set up a query to list the parent item.
2. Select the parent item from the query result, and click the option "**Export to CSV**" to export the parent item into a CSV file.

[image]

3. Open the CSV file to edit. Change the existing '**`Title`**' column to '**`Title 1`**', and add the new '**`Title 2`**' column after '**`Title 1`**'.
4. Do not change any thing in the row of the parent item (the second row).
5. Since the third row, add the required types (under **`Work Item Type`** column), required titles (under **`Title 2`** column) and other optional fields of the child items.

[image]

6. After the update, save the CSV file, then go to go to "Boards" > "Queries" on Azure DevOps to import the items from with the CSV file.

[image]

Comment: Hi @BdR, I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Just want to say hi and whether you have received my answer?
Have you tried as the steps suggested in my answer? Are they helpful for you?
As suggested, you can export the parent item into a CSV file and update in this CSV file, then import with this updated CSV file.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, yes I saw it. But that is another way to construct the import CSV file to get the same situation as the Notepad in my original screenshot. So that it contains the ID and Title of the original user story and an extra `Title 2` column. However, when I add a column named `Description` it overwrites the User Story description, and when I add `Description 2` I get `Duplicate non-required column headers: Description`. So our "solution" workaround for now is to simply not use the Description at all for any of the Issue items.